# ST_Intersects AND ST_Touches combination is much slower with large geometry input

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, sql, intersection

I am trying to `geom` columns from multiple table and later combining with a table which only has `linestrings`, I am finding lines which are not intersecting OR just touching the union of geom columns. But it's very slow. The result of `union` is single row with size ~ `160kb`.
I have tried using `ST_Subdivide` but still the result is same. I also tried using `ST_DWithin()` but still no luck.

```sql
WITH union_table AS (
    SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS geom FROM (
    SELECT geom FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT geom FROM table2)
),
intersection_table AS (
    SELECT table3.geom FROM table3
    LEFT JOIN union_table ut ON ut.something = table3.something
    WHERE
    (ST_Intersects(table3.geom, ut.geom) = false OR
    ST_Touches(table3.geom, ut.geom) = true)
)
SELECT geom FROM intersection_table
```

Comment: Do your tables have spatial indexes?

Comment: In `(ST_intersects(table3.geom, ut.geom)` comparing with union feels heavy and not necessary. If table3.geom intersects with any geometry in table1 or table2 then it intersects with the union as well. But you seem still to require union for finding the geometries that touch the unioned geometry.

Comment: Since I am creating table CTE and using those in the final query, so No spatial indexes. But in base table indexes are there @BERA

Comment: Correct, that is for ```ST_touches``` @user30184

Comment: I think that I would make tests by saving interim results like union and sub-divided union into physical tables with spatial indexes and progressing step by step to find out if complicated SQL drops the spatial index.

Comment: I have tried creating that too but still the query is slower. It uses index but still take too long @user30184

Comment: Subdividing should help a lot. I have no other ideas, let's see if some real experts get interested. If you run ST_Intersects = false and ST_Touches = true individually, is one or the other especially slow?

Comment: What is slow? What have you subdivided (the line or the unioned polygon?)? How have you subdivided it? Is the unioned polygon a simple polyon or a multi-polygon?

Comment: Since you have the `ut` table in the `where` clause, don't use a `left join` but a regular `join`. If the line bounding box intersects the unioned polygon bounding box, a spatial index will be of no use and the intersection/touch will always have to be computed. I would work with single part polygons and if subdivisions of the lines, maybe densifying the vertices first

Comment: @JGH ```ST_touches``` is slow. ```ST_intersects``` is still taking less time. 
I have tried using subdivision but it doesn't work. Also tried replacing ```LEFT JOIN``` with ```JOIN```, but still taking long time

Comment: "slow" is very subjective. "it doesn't work" also and you still haven't explained what and how you have subdivided... if basic optimization doesn't work, you would have to provide timings, `explain (buffers, analyze)` plans, and the query/ies you have used

Comment: Geometry overlay performance is related to the *product* of the vertex count of the geometries involved. Therefore it is completely unsurprising that a large feature would process more slowly.

Comment: don't use CTE for large geometry tables as you lose the index

Comment: @IanTurton But I am creating most of the geometry records in CTE tables, can't do it without CTE.

Comment: Unfortunately the current implementation of ST_Touches is sub-optimal, so its slow.  Hopefully we can improve this in PostGIS.

Comment: You should be able to always rewrite a CTE as a sub query, or worst case a new temp table with indexes, to allow the query planner to see more of the data and indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spatial *non*-predicates are tricky. Usually you want to inverse your problem definition to gain on performance and simplicity; e.g. in this case:

> *Find all `target.geom`s that spatially **overlap** with `reference.geom`s, then select all `target.geoms` that are **not** in the above set.*

In PostgreSQL/PostGIS you would want to try a correlated exclusion filter query, i.e. using `EXISTS` like so:

```
SELECT
  tgt.*
FROM
  table3 AS tgt
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      table1 AS ref
    WHERE
      ST_Crosses(tgt.geom, ref.geom)
  )
UNION
SELECT
  tgt.*
FROM
  table3 AS tgt
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      table2 AS ref
    WHERE
      ST_Crosses(tgt.geom, ref.geom)
  )
;
```

or

```
SELECT
  tgt.*
FROM
  table3 AS tgt
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      table1 AS ref
    WHERE
      ST_Crosses(tgt.geom, ref.geom)
  )
  OR
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      table2 AS ref
    WHERE
      ST_Crosses(tgt.geom, ref.geom)
  )
```

*It is possible that the planner actually runs the same execution plan for both queries, or that it may be able to spin up worker threads in the `UNION`'ed approach. The `OR`'ed approach is likely a tad faster by itself - but test yourself.*

**Depending on your geometry setup**, you'd need switch from `ST_Crosses` to `ST_Overlaps` - see their docs for when either one is suitable. If none applies, use `ST_Relate` in conjunction with a `&&` filter.

`UNION` (without `ALL`) will return a result set of distinct row value combinations - which doesn't come for free, but *should* beat other means of set distinction here (you could try an outer `GROUP BY` to compare).

---

Needless to say, eliminating the need to filter from *two* reference tables per query would certainly have the most significant effect - if you can, and plan to run this over and over, consider merging `table1.geom` and `table2.geom` into a separate relation (referenced from the source tables via PK).

Comment: @postgis-user which one was fastest? Can you share your PostgreSQL & PostGIS version info here in a comment, and, if you have the time, I'd also like to see the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) <query>` plans of both queries - would you mind posting them on [depesz](https://explain.depesz.com/) for me (you can obfuscate the plan to not share any confidential info)?

Comment: The first approach is faster.

Comment: @postgis-user it really needs to be an `OR`, not an `AND` in the second query. That's been a dumb mistake, and also a potential performance improvement...